How do I install Mice and pointing devices in device manager without using a mouse?
My mouse was working but following the use of a driver updater it stopped.
Sadly, Mice and pointing devices is not showing in device manager. I want to view hidden devices to see if it has been hidden, but have no mouse to open view.
Is there another way?
Or is it possible to add Mice and pointing devices to device manager in any way without the use of a mouse?

Which version of Windows?

Aint 3.11 -.- ,any win from XP(not 100% sure i recoil 95 had it the same way) onward should have this ability and should work in this manner.

Press WinKey+R and in Run box type "compmgmt.msc" and press enter.

On next screen you can use;

Tab key(just above Caps Lock) to switch between window view
Arrow keys to move cursor and navigate
Context menu key(it should be on right side from Spacebar, after AltGr, not all keyboards have it). If context menu button is absent you can try with combination "Shit+F10", this replaces Right Mouse button
Enter or Spacebar(depending on where you are in what window) will be used as
Left Mouse button
Also using left Alt will give you access to top side of Menu


You want to get to "YourPCname", right click it and choose "Scan for hardware changes", this should automatically fix your issue with mouse driver and install it.
EDIT: Once in Device manager, you can use Alt, to get in top menu, and under View you will find "Show hidden devices" (or Alt V W key-press)


You can use the keyboard to move mouse cursor: https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000542.htm. And in a dialog, Ctrl-Tab changes to the next tab.

Hi! Thank you so much for answering my question. I have the screen shown for device mananager and I have the grey box Scan for hardware changes. I have pressed tab nothing happens, enter and the grey box disappears, shift and F10 it returns, right cursor - nothing, down cursor - box turns blue but press enter

Any suggestions of what I am doing wrong?

You can check under Human Interface Devices, if you have mouse there, try to get options and select Uninstall (Deleting drivers, it will offer a tick if possible on next screen that appears). If there are none, i would advise that you test with new mouse. Consider you might need IT guy to actually take a look if computer became faulty.

Example how mouse(s) can appear https://i.postimg.cc/prGywVPz/Snimka-zaslona-2024-04-28-141830.png
